# Codeigniter:Soap Client call works well in PHP not in C#

Tags: c#, php, web-services, codeigniter, soap

I created a SOAP server in codeigniter and here is my controller

```
class Sample extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
      $ns = base_url();
      $this->load->library("Nusoap_library");
      $this->load->library("Master"); 
      $this->server = new soap_server(); // create soap server object
      $this->server->configureWSDL("SOAP", $ns); // wsdl 
      $this->server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $ns; // server namespace
}

public function index()
{
    $ns = base_url();
    $input_array = array ('type' => "xsd:string"); // "addnumbers" method parameters
    $return_array = array ("fruit" => "xsd:string");
    $this->server->register('Master.fruits', $input_array, $return_array, "urn:SOAPServerWSDL", "urn:".$ns."/addnumbers", "rpc", "encoded", "Fruit Types");
    $this->server->service(file_get_contents("php://input")); // read raw data from request body
}

public function client(){
    $this->client = new nusoap_client(base_url()."index.php?wsdl", true);
    $this->load->view("client");
}
}
```

the server is works very well, and i created a Mater class  as library
Master.php [library]

```
class Master {

    public function fruits($type)
    {
         switch($type)
         {
            case 'red':
            return "Apple";
            break;a
            case 'yellow':
            return "banana";
            break;
         }
    }
}
```

As you can see the controller, i also created a client function to test whether the client working fine

here is my client View code

```
$error = $this->client->getError();
if ($error) {
    echo "<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
}

$result = $this->client->call("Master.fruits", array("type" => "red"));

if ($this->client->fault) {
    echo "<h2>Fault</h2><pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>";
}
else {
    $error = $this->client->getError();
    if ($error) {
        echo "<h2>Error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<h2>Fruits</h2><pre>";
        echo $result;
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

i am getting result perfectly in php while calling the SOAP server but if the same SOAP server is called via C# by creating service

i am getting errors something like it should not be like Master.fruits it should be like masterfruits and also i am getting errors in content Type

Comment: The C# code could have been useful you know ;)

Comment: I am just adding the client service not something complex,